# Which Ubuntu ISO should I burn for my system?

Tags: installation, boot, iso, versions, burning

When I am downloading Ubuntu to burn it and install on a partition, I keep getting the amd version (`ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`). I don't have an amd processor but I have intel i7 3740QM.

On the [download page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) I just see one link that's interesting (12.04 since it's stable), no option for intel processors. Should I still use this file?

I found another ISO file earlier but I'm not sure from there. It's filename is `ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-i386.iso` and I burned a CD from it. The reason I think it may be wrong is that when I'm booting from it I get the following message:

> ata_id[334]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for ´/dev/sdc´: Invalid argument

The boot stops there and I need to go reconfigure BIOS or eject the CD to boot again.

I figured there's something wrong with my CD so I'll burn another one so that's why I want to be sure I'm using the right ISO to burn.

[In this questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103065/why-do-i-get-hdio-get-identity-failed-message-when-booting-with-external-usb-h) there's someone getting the same or similar error message. Answers suggests that the message can be ignored - but I don't get further, that message is shown and the boot is not proceeding.

Comment: You can use the i386 iso on just about any PC.  The amd64 iso is for 64-bit capable processors; not just The ones from AMD.  Take a look at this question [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034/107450)

Comment: WarrenHill Thanks, I have burnt both now and as I boot from the CD I still get that error message (sometimes ata_id[333]). If that problem is because the OS can't find my disk drive, then how come it's trying to boot from it, as @thefourtheye suggests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to install a 64 bit version of Ubuntu, if your processor architecture supports it. [amd64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) iso corresponds to 64 bit version of Ubuntu.

And its called amd64 because, the original specifications for x86-64 was created by AMD. (Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)

Your processor supports 64 bit instruction set. (Source : http://ark.intel.com/products/70847). So you can use amd64 iso.

And this error

`ata_id[334]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for ´/dev/sdc´: Invalid argument`

is most likely because of the OS unable to identify your Disk Drive. For more information about it, read this question [Ubuntu not booting from CD or USB, how can I make sure OS finds my drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312217/ubuntu-not-booting-from-cd-or-usb-how-can-i-make-sure-os-finds-my-drive)