# Ubuntu not booting from CD or USB, how can I make sure OS finds my drive?

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot, usb, startup

I've been trying several different installation methods to install Ubuntu on my partition. No matter what kind of installation type (CD or USB), I get the same error message.

At first I assumed I was using the incorrect Ubuntu version but I'm quite confident I'm on the right path after this question:

[Which Ubuntu ISO should I burn for my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290703/which-ubuntu-iso-should-i-burn-for-my-system)

I am trying to install Ubuntu on a machine that has Windows 8 natively installed according to this answer by Luis Alvarado: [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system)

UEFI is on, secure boot is off and the disc/USB loads properly.

From the CD I simply get the error message when booting, but when booting from USB (created USB according to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) I get to choose to run Ubuntu without installing, or to install it.

Either (both) of these options gives me the following error message:

```
ata_id[334]: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY failed for '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument
```

User 'thefourtheye' suggested in my previous question that this error message is due to that the OS is unable to identify by disk drive. That is entirely possible - but how do I solve it?

Some say that there's something wrong with the drivers for Ubuntu to ID the USB, and that I could write my own drivers for that. It seems a bit over my head though.

Burning program used was imgburn for the CD, from `SetupImgBurn_2.5.7.0.exe`. I burnt the image to the disc, it was recognized as a boot disc and when inspecting the CD's content it looked as it should according to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromCD

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: which cd-burning-program do you use under windows 8 ? Have you burnt an iso-image-cd or have you made a simple data-cd (not booting). To burn a booting CD with success you drag the Ubuntu*.iso-file from first-little-window (where downloaded files all are lying) into second-little-window (where is displayed the "content" of cd to burn). Sorry - have read too quick your lines. You used USB-stick and not CD...

Comment: Thanks @dschinn1001 I have updated my question with how the burning process was done. I feel though as if I'm getting on better with the USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provide that you made your USB-stick bootable and after plug-in your USB-stick ... - you need to edit Bios-settings (press key 'F2' at beginning of reboot). Disable Uefi-Bios and enable Efi-Bios. Then in Boot-Order of devices your USB-stick should be set at first place of all booting devices (hard-disk at second place). Then save edits and reboot.

`HDIO_GET_IDENTITY` refers to your hard-disk which is a new-brand. Though Ubuntu has mostly the newest drivers, your hard-disk is newer. You might be able to get passed this by trying a newer version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I have enabled/disabled Uefi/Efi, setup boot order and successfully started boot from both CD and USB, however when the boot starts I get this error message.

Comment: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY refers to your hard-disk which is a new-brand. Though Ubuntu has mostly the newest drivers, your hard-disk is newer. When you are patient it dissappears after 3 to 6 months and your hard-disk is supported then too. Here is same message popping up with an usb-harddisk: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103065/why-do-i-get-hdio-get-identity-failed-message-when-booting-with-external-usb-h

Comment: Thanks @dschinn1001 for that useful answer. Does this mean that I might be more successful trying Ubuntu 13.02? Perhaps new drivers are introduced.

Comment: I have created a USB with Ubuntu 13.02, reset all my bios setting (including secure boot and Uefi) hoping this newer version would have support for my new disk and it does. Ubuntu is now installed perfectly on my partition. Thank you all!